# map with array of keys in Angular 2 ..?

Tags: angular

here i am trying to use map with array of keys "map.get(["4354jgv","A"])" is undefine, howw do i suppose to get value

```
let map = new Map()
map.set(["4354jgv","A"],1)
map.set("B",2)
map.set("C",3);

console.log(map.get(["4354jgv","A"]));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
const KEY1 = ["4354jgv","A"];
map.set(KEY1, 'hello');
console.log(map.get(KEY1));
```